# Can I Update A Label In Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, var

This is an example.
`size = 2
label = Label(tk, text=size)
label.pack()
size = 3`
Can i update the label to say 3?

Comment: You need the `config` method for the label. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method

Comment: What do you mean, give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just used the `config` method:

```
label = Label(root,text="this is text!")
label.pack()

label.config(text="that was text!")
```

Another way to do this would be to set the `textvariable` attribute of the label.

```
textvar = StringVar()
textvar.set("this is text!")
label = Label(root,textvariable=textvar)
label.pack()

textvar.set("that was text!")
```

In this case the `label` instance will automatically update its text when the `textvar` instance is updated.

Comment: Can "this" be a variable.

Comment: It isn't a variable, it is a string.

Comment: why is a textvariable better if doing it regularly? What's the gain of `textvar.set("this is text!")` over `label.config("this is text!")`? In both cases you're doing a function call to set the value. Adding a variable just introduces a new object to manage, which provides no extra value in this case.

Comment: My reasons are likely subjective, but I find that doing it in this way facilitates a better logical decomposition of my code. However, as you say there is no strong objective argument for doing it this way. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Also you could imagine an example where you have multiple labels that are all associated with the same `textvariable`. In this case you would not need to loop over the labels to update the text, you would simply update the `textvariable` and the labels would be updated automatically.